# Render view (BI) like behind a veil

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

I regard myself as having no broad knowledge with blender.
I am building up a view of a town over months and everything was fine, including rendered views and animations. Now, as of a sudden, I have problems with rendering (BI), everything is like behind a veil, no details anymore (but weakly visible behind the veil). Texture view is ok, when I set the material of a face to Shading->shadeless (ticked) the render view is clearer, but without Shadeless ticked it is veiled. Pls see pictures.
I cannot tick for every material (several thousands) to make them fully visible again. I might have hit a hot key by chance (or it has happened with recent installation problems with a different software). I cannot find any possibility in Blender to switch this off.
I am hoping for some help. Thanks.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a .blend file showing the issue. It's very difficult to guess what the problem might be by looking at a picture.

Have you tried reducing the illumination?

Comment: What the @oblomov said, plus but use only one object, not whole town on the scene to limit the weight of the file.